# HTML video speed controller for Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, avplayer, vlc

I'm trying to find a way to control the speed of a custom HTML video playback app that I use for work. It is designed for and only runs in Internet Explorer. I've tried messing around in the console with some of the commands others have recommended but they keep throwing me errors. The Application we use takes VLC video files and plays back the audio. VLC has a way to control playback speed, but I can't figure out how to control that through the application either. In the console I've tried:

```
document.querySelector('video').defaultPlaybackRate = 2.0;
```

and

```
document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = 1.25;
```

but they both give me the error:

> Unable to set property 'defaultPlaybackRate' of undefined or null reference

or 'playbackRate' for the other command.

In either instance, it seems like 'video' is a variable I need to assign? I've tried substituting the file name of the specific file I'm trying to play, but it still gives me syntax errors.

edit:

I've also tried:

```
const video=document.querySelector(nowPlaying);
video.playbackRate=2;
```

which gives me a syntax error.

edit 2:

As requested, here is a sample of the code I've been playing with today. The functions like slower(); and pause(); are not defined anywhere in the rest of the code; I'm thinking they may be VLC functions? If that is the case perhaps there is a VLC function I can call that will change the playback speed for me, but I can't find anything in VLC's code.

```
 <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr>
  <td id="buttons" align="left">
    <a href="#" onMouseover="window.status='speed down'; return true;" onMouseout="window.status=' '; return true;">
     <img src="backstop.gif" onClick="slower();" border="0" title="jump backward"/></a>
    <a href="#" onMouseover="window.status='jump backward'; return true;" onMouseout="window.status=' '; return true;">
     <img src="slower.gif" onClick="bumpBackward();" border="0" title="jump backward"/></a>
    <a href="#" onMouseover="window.status='play'; return true;" onMouseout="window.status=' '; return true;">
     <img src="forward.gif" onClick="play();"  border="0" title="play"/></a>
    <a href="#" onMouseover="window.status='stop'; return true;" onMouseout="window.status=' '; return true;">
     <img src="stop.gif" onClick="stop();"  border="0" title="stop"/></a>
    <a href="#" onMouseover="window.status='pause'; return true;" onMouseout="window.status=' '; return true;">
     <img src="pause.gif" onClick="pause();"  border="0" title="pause"/></a>
    <a href="#" onMouseover="window.status='jump forward'; return true;" onMouseout="window.status=' '; return true;">
     <img src="faster.gif" onClick="bumpForward();"  border="0" title="jump forward"/></a>
    <a href="#" onMouseover="window.status='speed up'; return true;" onMouseout="window.status=' '; return true;">
     <img src="forwardstop.gif" onClick="faster();" border="0" title="jump backward"/></a>
  </td>
  <td id="playtime" align="right"></td>
</tr>
```

Note: The first and last buttons were added by me while I was messing around.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, there are two main problems:

First, `Unable to set property of undefined or null reference` means that you didn't get the page elements correctly, you may use it before the page is loaded, and this problem occurs. If this is the case, you need to put the script code in window.onload(). A simple demo:

```
<head>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById('slowerBtn').onclick = function () {
                document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = 0.5;
            }
            document.getElementById('fasterBtn').onclick = function () {
                document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = 2;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <video controls="controls">
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
    <br />
    <input type="button" name="slowerBtn" id="slowerBtn" value="Slower" />
    <input type="button" name="fasterBtn" id="fasterBtn" value="Faster" />
</body>
```

Second, the required parameter of [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#parameters) is a valid element selector. What is the parameter `nowPlaying` you provided? I think it should be invalid.

If you can post your code sample, this will better identify the cause of the problem and solve it.

Comment: I can post a code sample, but I'm not sure what part of the code would be useful. It is a 500+ line file with next to no comments, and I have a pretty rudimentary understanding of HTML. nowPlaying was just an attempt to pick out a variable in the code and hope things would work without a ton of extra effort. I've added a chunk of code that I've been playing with today, but it might not be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure how the relevant script code is executed, so I can't determine your question, have you tried window.onload() in my answer above? On the other hand, as described in the document already mentioned, `nowPlaying` must be a css selector string. If it does not follow the specification, the code will not execute correctly.